# Change my username

Tags: support, user-accounts

I would like to change my username, but when I first attempted it it gave me an error. 
I fixed the thing it was squabbling about, but then it said I could only change my username every 30 days (it said I could change it again in 22 hours???) and then it wouldn't let me change my username (I haven't.)

I would appreciate any help (mod's: Maybe a bug?)

Answer (score 7):

You've been a member for almost 30 days. Hence, the first time you changed (read as created) your username was about 29 days and 2 hours ago. In 22 hours it'll be 30 days and you can then change your user name.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this as soon as I can!

Comment: In this context I'd like to point out that there are several misleading dialogues on stackexchange (like when you (too late) try to change a vote).